# Port is closed on Azure Linux VM even though allowed by network security group (NSG)

Tags: azure, ssh, rtsp, portforwarding, azure-linux

here's my scenario:

I have IP camera behind the company firewall that I want to stream publicly, and for that, I've created two Azure VMs (Ubuntu 19.04) - let's call them `vm1` and `vm2`

In case it's important, my VM SKU is `Standard B1s (1 vcpus, 1 GiB memory)`

1. I SSH to my camera and from there, I do a remote port forwarding for RTSP like this:

   ```
   ssh -R 554:localhost:554 root@<vm1-ip>
   ```

   And, I guess I need to enable root SSH because it's a "well-known" port.
2. I log in to `vm1`, and I see it's listening on the port: `sudo netstat -tlnp` gives me this:

   ```
   Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:554           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      108748/sshd: root@p
   tcp6       0      0 ::1:554                 :::*                    LISTEN      108748/sshd: root@p
   ```
3. But, when I use `nmap` from from `vm2`, the port is shown as closed:

   ```
   nmap <vm1-ip> -p 554

   PORT    STATE  SERVICE
   554/tcp closed rtsp
   ```
4. When I use `vlc` to connect to the stream, it doesn't work either: the URL I use in `vlc` is: `rtsp://<vm1-ip>/...`
5. I thought this might be an issue with the NSG (network security group) associated with `vm1`, so I tried allowing all inbound traffic:
   [image]
   and, needless to say that it doesn't solve the issue

Any thoughts on this?

Thank you

Comment: You could potentially use `socat` to map ports on the remote host, nullifying the need for a tunnel on a reserved port. See this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/564604

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it with enabling the **GatewayPorts** option on the SSH server configuration file on the Azure VM. This option allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports. By default, it is set to no, which means that only connections from the loopback address (127.0.0.1) are allowed.

To enable the GatewayPorts option, you need to do the following steps:

- Log in to the Azure VM as root or a user with sudo privileges.
- Edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file with your preferred text editor, such as nano or vi.
- Find the line that says #GatewayPorts no and uncomment it by removing the # symbol. Then change the value from no to yes or clientspecified. The yes value means that the SSH server will bind the local port to any address, while the clientspecified value means that the SSH client will specify the address to bind to. For example, you can use `-R 554:0.0.0.0:554` to bind to any address, or `-R 554:127.0.0.1:554` or `-R 554:localhost:554` to bind to a specific address.
- Save and close the file.
- Restart the SSH service with the command sudo systemctl restart sshd or sudo service sshd restart, depending on your Linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue for me today. Resolved by changing the port as [suggested here](https://superuser.com/questions/1552838/ssh-forwarding-through-putty-not-working-on-windows-10):

> The recommended port range is from 1024 to 49151.

Furthermore, as already pointed out in the other answer by @Saman, the port can appear closed when scanned from vm2 also because it's bound to localhost, which means it's only accessible from vm1 itself.

I also disabled a service in failure state and rebooted the VM. In some cases, SSH connections may fail to establish or become unresponsive due to system overload and CPU throttling. When a system experiences high CPU usage, it may struggle to process incoming SSH requests efficiently, leading to connection timeouts or failures.
Another reason of delay for ssh is an obsolete record in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` for example because the public IP was associated to a different machine before.

Eventually, you could try [this tunneling example](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling-example#remote-forwarding)

```
# change GatewayPorts in sshd_config
ssh -R <vm2-ip>:1554:localhost:554 root@<vm1-ip>
```